# How to split text kipping id?

Tags: r, split

I have this data frame on R :

```
id   value
1    "i want it"
2    "you hate me"
3    " they know"
```

==>3 comments identified by id

Now i'ld like to split comments, but keeping id for each word:

```
id   word
1    i
1    want
1    it
2    you
2    hate
2    me
3    they
3    Know
```

I tried using split, sapply... but i dont see how can i do it.
Someone can help me?

Thx for your help

Comment: It is crazy how many times this question has been asked the last 10 days!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'value', sep=" ", "long")
#   id value
#1:  1     i
#2:  1  want
#3:  1    it
#4:  2   you
#5:  2  hate
#6:  2    me
#7:  3  they
#8:  3  know
```